# Can I use latter when there is only one option?

Tags: grammar, formality

In this sentence, "***latter***" sounds good to me (but I am not a native English speaker).

> Over successive stages of the model the urban population evolves to the optimal solution. ***The latter*** is reached when there are negligible
> changes in the dynamic of each individual.

If it is not correct, what would be a good choice? The context is *the model of demographic evolution*.

Comment: When you use 'latter' there should be 'former' too.  Which is that 'former'?

Comment: Try “which is reached...”

Comment: Latter is primarily a locational word, which frequently coincides with later in time because we tend to describe things in that order. But it is a comparative, and there isn't anything else in the sentence sufficiently parallel with which to compare. Also, I would use "equilibrium solution".

Comment: You'd be better off saying something like "Said solution is reached ..." But why not just use a comma followed by "which": "... population evolves to the optimal solution, which is reached when ..."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do so and remain grammatical, because latter is a comparative word ([it compares one item to another in sequence](https://www.dictionary.com/e/former-vs-latter/)), and so necessarily requires two options. In your sentence, **latter** confuses the reader because there is only one thing being compared and the sequence is not apparent.

Answer (score 0):

No, *latter* doesn't work unless you are referencing the second of two things mentioned.

You could try:

*Over successive stages of the model, the urban population evolves to the optimal solution, which is reached when there are negligible changes in the dynamic of each individual.*

Or:

*Over successive stages of the model, the urban population evolves to the optimal solution—the point at which there are negligible changes in the dynamic of each individual.*

(Note that you need a comma after your introductory phrase.)

Comment: What if the first part and second clauses are longer and I wanna put a period to separate them. Which is the best way to connect them?

Comment: Maybe:  *Over successive stages of the model, the urban population evolves to the "optimal solution." The optimal solution is defined as the point at which there are negligible changes in the dynamic of each individual in the population.*

Comment: OK so you guys don't mind repetitions. It would be bad in my language.

Comment: Would "This is defined as" be fine? Or don't you like starting with "this" and you would rather repeat?

Comment: Yes, *This is defined as* is fine.